# Login to many context in modx using api functions

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am working in facebook login, after successful facebook authentication i want to login user using modx api, i am able to login him using below code. But i am not getting how to login to multiple contexts, i tried to pass "login_context" parameter but still it only login him in "web" context and not other contexts.

```
 $c = array(
   'login_context' => 'tech,data,finance',
   'username' => $username,
   'password' => $password,
   'returnUrl' => 'http://www.mydomain.com',
 );
 $response = $modx->runProcessor('security/login', $c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loginContext` its for only one context, if you need to login to multiple contexts - use [add_contexts](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/156a71c760577ba6e8910b66cc52b4631c572d86/core/model/modx/processors/security/login.class.php#L44) option.

Comment: It didnt worked, so i am now using hidden iframe method.

Comment: It worked with the latest version of modx, Vasis thanks again. I am posting my code below for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

This is just basic code to give you simple idea how it can be done.

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)){
   $username = $_POST['uname'];
   $password = $_POST['upass'];
   $c = array(
    'login_context' => 'web', // main context
    'add_contexts' => 'profile,gallery,videos', // other contexts
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
  );

  $response = $modx->runProcessor('security/login',$c);

  if($response){
    if (!$response->isError()) {
      if($response->response['success'] == 1){
        echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
      }else{
        echo json_encode($response->response);   
      }
    }else{
      echo json_encode($response->response); 
    }
  }
}
```